# Web scraping multiple pages issue

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the first 4 pages from the following site for educational purposes using R code:

https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?searchTab=1&page=3&sort=date-d&zipcodeFrom=1000&zipcodeTo=2499&street=

```
{r}
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

url_base <- "https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?searchTab=1&page=%d&sort=date-d&zipcodeFrom=1000&zipcodeTo=2499&street="

map_df(1:4,function(i){
  page <- read_html(sprintf(url_base,i))

  data.frame(Address = html_text(html_nodes(page,".font-weight-bolder.text-left")))
}) -> Address_map
View(Address_map)
```

The only issue with this code is that it does not actually show me the first 4 pages, but instead it provides me with the first page four times.

I hope you can help in fixing this small issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot of the quick reply. Can you recommend how to code this in R? I tried a few solutions, but none of them really gave a relevant result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page uses javascript to call an API, you can access the data, in JSON format, like this for the first page: `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.boliga.dk/api/v2/sold/search/results?searchTab=1&page=1&sort=date-d&zipcodeFrom=1000&zipcodeTo=2499&street=")`

To put together all 4 pages, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

url_base <- "https://api.boliga.dk/api/v2/sold/search/results?searchTab=1&page=%d&sort=date-d&zipcodeFrom=1000&zipcodeTo=2499&street="

Address_map <-lapply(1:4,function(i){
  print(i)
  # pause to prevent attacking the server
  Sys.sleep(2)
  #retrieve the results data frame from the returned data structure
  fromJSON(sprintf(url_base, i))$result
}) 

#bind everything together
answer <- bind_rows(Address_map)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is excellent. Can you maybe explain what exactly this API is all about and why your solution worked? Just out of curiosity - i have marked your solution as working already!

Comment: Here is a very general explanation.  The data is stored in a some database on the server and not on the webpage.  When a web page is loaded the web page's script will query the database via the call to ""https://api.boliga.dk/api/v2/..." and the data is returned as a JSON data structure.  Therefore in order to scrape the web page, one either needs to query the database directly or make the request act like a web browser and run the javascript, as mentioned in the other answer with RSelenium, for example.

Comment: @Dave2e Please, Could you explain how you got the API address ""api.boliga.dk/api/v2..." from the page
As iam tring to do the same in this page
"https://www.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::59|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::33%3Ceq_market_cap;1"

Comment: @BatmanFan, In your browser, open your developer tools.  Goto the network tab (reload web page). You are looking for a XHR file.  Scroll through the list to find the correct file and copy the link.  This does not always work, depending on how and when the query is generated.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Look what happens if you paste the result of `sprintf(url_base,2)` into a browser, it loads the website at table 1. So I think you cannot scrape this data with rvest, you need a package like `RSelenium` to scrape this data. With `RSelenium` you can access the website and then move to the second table etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am relatively new to R, so do you have an idea of how this code would look like for just picking up addresses in my URL?